# Why does the Common Lisp's apply function give a different result?

Tags: common-lisp

When I try this code on Emacs `SLIME`, the `apply` function gives a different result. Isn't it supposed to give the same result? Why does it give a different result? Thanks.

```
CL-USER> (apply #'(lambda (n)
             (cons n '(b a))) '(c)) 

(C B A)

CL-USER> (cons '(c) '(b a)) 

((C) B A)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cons` takes an *element* and a *list* as arguments. So `(cons 'x '(a b c d))` will return `(x a b c d)`.

`apply` takes a function and a *list of arguments* -- but the arguments will *not* be passed to the function as a list! They will be split and passed individually:

```
(apply #'+ '(1 2 3))

6
```

(actually, it takes one function, several arguments, of which the *last* must be a list -- this list will be split and treated as "the rest of the arguments to the function". try, for example, `(apply #'+ 5 1 '(1 2 3))`, which will return `12`)

Now to your code:

The last argument you passed to the `apply` function is `'(c)`, a *list* with one element, `c`. Apply will treat it as a list of arguments, so the *first argument you passed* to your `lambda`-form is `c`.

In the second call, you passed `'(c)` as first argument to `cons`. This is a *list*, which was correctly included in the first place of the resulting list: `( (c) b a)`.

The second call would be equivalent to the first if you did

```
(cons 'c '(b a))

(c b a)
```

And the first call would be equivalent to the second if you did

```
(apply #'(lambda (n) (cons n '(b a))) '((c)))

((c) b a)
```

Comment: Oh yes.  It's mainly a matter of giving arguments to the apply function, it seems. The equivalent code samples makes it quite clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
CL-USER 51 > (cons '(c) '(b a))
((C) B A)

CL-USER 52 > (apply #'(lambda (n)
                        (cons n '(b a)))
                    '(c))
(C B A)
```

Let's use `FUNCALL`:

```
CL-USER 53 > (funcall #'(lambda (n)
                          (cons n '(b a)))
                      '(c))
((C) B A)
```

See also what happens when we apply a two element list:

```
CL-USER 54 > (apply #'(lambda (n)
                        (cons n '(b a)))
                    '(c d))

Error: #<anonymous interpreted function 40600008E4> got 2 args, wanted 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a symmetry between &rest arguments in functions and `apply`.

```lisp
(defun function-with-rest (arg1 &rest argn)
  (list arg1 argn))

(function-with-rest 1)         ; ==> (1 ())
(function-with-rest 1 2)       ; ==> (1 (2))
(function-with-rest 1 2 3 4 5) ; ==> (1 (2 3 4 5))
```

Imagine we want to take `arg1` and `argn` and use it the same way with a function of our choice in the same manner as `function-with-rest`. We double the first argument and sum the rest.

```lisp
(defun double-first-and-sum (arg1 &rest argn)
  (apply #'+ (* arg1 2) argn)) 

(double-first-and-sum 1 1)     ; ==> 3
(double-first-and-sum 4 5 6 7) ; ==> 26
```

The arguments between the function and the list of "rest" arguments are additional arguments that are always first:

```lisp
(apply #'+ 1 '(2 3 4)) ; ==> (+ 1 2 3 4)
(apply #'+ 1 2 3 '(4)) ; ==> (+ 1 2 3 4)
```

This is very handy since often we want to add more arguments than we are passed (or else we could just have used the function `apply` is using in the first place. Here is something called `zip`:

```lisp
(defun zip (&rest args)
  (apply #'mapcar #'list args))
```

So what happens when you call it like this: `(zip '(a b c) '(1 2 3))`? Well args will be `((a b c) (1 2 3))` and the `apply` will make it become `(mapcar #'list '(a b c) '(1 2 3))` which will result in `((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))`. Do you see the symmetry?

Thus you could in your example you could have done this:

```lisp
(apply #'(lambda (&rest n)
            (cons n '(b a))) '(c)) 
;==> ((c) b a)

(apply #'(lambda (&rest n)
            (cons n '(b a))) '(c d e)) 
;==> ((c d e) b a)
```

Comment: Helpful examples. The first example in particular (function-with-rest 1) shows how arguments are passed in a list because when no arguments are given, an empty list is returned.